# Android MediaPlayer gives null exception

Tags: android, media-player

Can someone help me with this strange issue, I want to play an audio file from SDCard , this is the code,I know that this is the right file path, but MediaPlayer gives me a null exception. Any help will be appreciated!

```
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/rockstar.mp3");
MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(file));
m.start();
```

This is stacktarce

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: always put logcat in question

Comment: Make sure your Sdcard is not in mass storage mode. By this your sdcard will not be available for your app to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not missing `.getAbsolutePath()`?

```
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/rockstar.mp3");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected, I will use this in my code, Many Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the right permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, which is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.
Log your path uri in LogCat to see if everything is correct, and start your media player like this :

```
   MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
   player.setDataSource("mnt/sdcard/music.mp3");
   player.prepare();
   player.start();
```

Comment: Glad to know that. Just to know, set your music file path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/rockstar.mp3"` as Bo. mentioned. I did it with hardcoded string just to show you the idea. Never used that method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
path+="/music.mp3"
mp.setDataSource(path)
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```