# Android MediaPlayer null Exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the Mediaplayer in Xamarin.Android working. My Code:

```
MediaPlayer player;
public void Play(string Filename)
{
    Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///android_asset/" + 
    Filename);
    Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player = MediaPlayer.Create(context, url);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
to an instance of an object.
```

The Exception occures on `player.Prepare()`. I have read [Android MediaPlayer gives null exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634769/android-mediaplayer-gives-null-exception) but wasn't working in my case.

Comment: and value of `Filename` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to use `player.SetDataSource()` instead of `MediaPlayer.create()`.
First, make sure the build action of your mp3 file is AndroidAsset.
Then you could use AssetManager to open your file with Filename.

For example:

```
    public void Play(string Filename)
    {           
        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = assets.OpenFd(Filename);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.SetDataSource(afd);
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();
    }
```

You can call this method by `Play("Demo.mp3")`

Comment: I am getting this error with your code: Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: One little change and it worked! this.Assets isnt working, call context.Assets instead. Thanks for the answer.